# Congratulations gnasher on clipping 100k!

Tags: discussion, reputation

It just came to my attention that [@gnasher729](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/16101/gnasher729) recently reached the 100k milestone.

Congratulations, gnasher!

Hope that you will be able to continue contributing to this wonderful Community.

Answer (score 5):

A solid accomplishment. Well done, and well deserved.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations!  I always enjoy your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Well done! Congratulations on your 100k milestone.